Can HDMI cable be modified to simulate TV is always on (even when turned off)?
Given a video source device (such as andoid-based "TV box") and video display device (such as flat panel TV) where there is an HDMI connection between them, is it possible to cut a specific wire in the HDMI cable, or tie a specific wire hi or low, or tie it to another wire, such that the source device will not recognize or see that the display device might have been turned off, so that the source device will never go into a sleep or stand-by mode?

why don't you ask how to?  instead of is it possible?

Would you mean something like this https://www.amazon.com.be/Dummy-Headless-Display-Emulator-60Hz-1Pack/dp/B07ZC9DBGK

Using a dummy plug takes up the HDMI connector on the source box, sure the source box now thinks there's a monitor connected to it, but then how am I going to see anything on my TV?

So, simple answer, can a cable be modified is unlikely, and you really don't want to just modify a cable.
It depends what your source box wants to see.
Maybe some in-line device such as a HDMI matrix or switch box or AV receiver can be bought and used. So instead of TV you may have to have another device on than the TV.
Setting HPD high alone will not do as then the source will not see anything active, and it can't be set high when TV is on the same wire. If HPD is high but then there is no EDID data available, unless you switch to a fake EDID such as those plugs you did not want to use. They might even terminate the high speed data lines to look like an active receiver.
It could be simpler to modify the Android box by rooting it and disabling entering sleep mode.
Or if it simply goes to sleep along with the TV becauses CEC messages, turn off CEC on either device.

Would an HDMI splitter (1 input 2 output) work?   Only 1 output would be used (going to the TV).  If the TV was on, then is turned off, would the splitter hold the line open, as if the TV was still on?  Android box is supplied by ISP, it has some sleep settings but not all of them, I've disabled sleep (or set it to highest time value) but box will go to sleep mode after a few hours when tv is off.  Turning TV back on does not automatically make box come back on and show video, sometimes it shows connection error or you need to press button on remote to wake it.
